# Alamofire 4.3 with Swift 3 , POST request does not working with URL Parameters

Tags: ios, post, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to send a post request as follows, My Router as follows

```
enum ProfieRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

case loginUser(parameters: Parameters)
case resetPassword(parametrs: Parameters)

var method: HTTPMethod {

    switch self {

    case .loginUser:
        return .post

    case .resetPassword:
        return .post
    }
}

var path: String {

    switch self {
    case .loginUser:
        return "app/api.php?request=login"

    case .resetPassword:
        return "app/api.php?request=forgettenPassword"
    }
}

func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let BASEURL = "https://www.example.com/"
    let url = try BASEURL.asURL()
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue


    switch self {

    case .loginUser(let parameters):
        urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)

    case .resetPassword(let parameters):
        urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    }
    return urlRequest
}
```

}

This is how i call it from ViewController,

```
@IBAction func signInButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "email": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(ProfieRouter.loginUser(parameters: parameters)).responseJSON{ response in


        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)

            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

But i got following error as follows,

```
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

Please note that, my API response is a valid when i checked with POSTMAN and Advanced REst Client. And i have tried several question regarding following error but non of them work in my case.

Please can someone point out the mistake i have done here.
Thank you.

Comment: when you use POSTMAN, do you use any **Http Request Header** values ?

Comment: yes i set Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, still the result is same

Comment: You are trying to use **.request(url : sample)**. instead of that use Alamofire.request() which contain **_ url:,
    method: ,
    parameters
    encoding:,
    headers:)
** parameters.

Comment: i am trying to use Alamofire.request(urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible). I tried option that u you have mentioned. It worked. But i need to apply the router concept here

Comment: a) can you post the http body you send when you do it with postman

Comment: b) i dont tested it - but you could try this: https://github.com/netguru/ResponseDetective ... maybe you can also post the log from there - to see the problems

Comment: i mean because it is a response and not a request error: we should check the response from Postman and the Response from alamofire. maybe can you add this as text to the question?

Comment: @muescha -  i can ensure that response is perfect and no any issue with that. I tested it with several REST api validators and it works fine. I think problem exists with this line  (var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path)))  ,  i will check the log as u mentioned

Comment: if it would ok then there should not an error. the error messages ('Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason') states exactly that this is a response error and not a request.

Comment: if you like to dig on the request side it is ok. but i think it is wasting of time.

Comment: you should check the response you get from alamofile before serialisation. and compare it with your REST response. if it is the same then dig more where the error comes from serialisation.

Comment: and without an codesample of this json nobody here can help you to dig into your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Modify you web-service calling code like this :

```
// Add default headers if needed.(As per your web-service requirement)
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Accept": "text/html",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

 Alamofire.request("Your URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

  debugPrint(response)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your time and effort, but as i have mentioned , i want to apply router concept here with URLRequestConvertible